# i try if statement javascript for form values but dosn't work?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

i need make if statement for form values to showing red notifications message if no or green message if yes
all form fields combobox except 2 fileds textbox
i need calculate this 2 textbox values = 12

so if all no + total values for text boxs = 12

showing green txt notifcation
else showing red txt notifcation

```
    <form name="ACV" method="post" action="mailto:yourname@mail.com?subject=ACV" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="Form1" onsubmit="return submitACV()">
<select name="Combobox1" size="1" id="Combobox1" style="position:absolute;left:33px;top:115px;width:200px;height:28px;z-index:0;">
<option value="No">NO</option>
<option value="yes">YES</option>
</select>
<select name="Combobox2" size="1" id="Combobox2" style="position:absolute;left:33px;top:148px;width:200px;height:28px;z-index:1;">
<option value="No">NO</option>
<option value="yes">YES</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="Editbox1" style="position:absolute;left:47px;top:248px;width:62px;height:16px;z-index:4;" name="Editbox1" value="" spellcheck="false">
<input type="text" id="Editbox2" style="position:absolute;left:161px;top:248px;width:62px;height:16px;z-index:5;" name="Editbox1" value="" spellcheck="false">
<input type="submit" id="Button1" name="" value="Submit" style="position:absolute;left:97px;top:310px;width:126px;height:21px;z-index:19;">
</form>


<script>
    function Button1 () {
        
        var text001;
        var answer1 = Combobox1.value
        var answer2 = Combobox2.value
        var answer3 = Combobox3.value
        var answer4 = Combobox4.value
        if (answer1 == "no");
if (answer2 == "no");
if (answer3 == "no");
if (answer4 == "no");
{
            
            text001 ="right !!";
            else
                text001 ="try again !!";
        }       
        
        
    }
    
    </script>
```

Comment: example for what i need https://www.elarabygroup.com/en/sharp-split-air-conditioner-1-5hp-cool-heat-standard-with-dry-and-turbo-function-in-white-color-ay-a12yse

Comment: Hint: put all the selects in an array, then use `array.every()`

Comment: `if (answer1 == "no"), (answer2 == "no"), (answer3 == "no"), (answer4 == "no"){` isn't valid JS

Comment: updated 
        if (answer1 == "no");
if (answer2 == "no");
if (answer3 == "no");
if (answer4 == "no");
{
            
            text001 ="right !!";
            else
                text001 ="try again !!";
        }       
        
        
    }